# One to Many Relationship on same table in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I am modeling Repositories on GitHub. Each Repo can have a set of forks, of which the Repo will be the parent of.

My partial model file looks like this:

```
class Repo(Base):
    __tablename__ = "repos"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Text, unique=True)
    parent_id = db.Column(Integer,db.ForeignKey('repos.id'))
    parent = db.relationship("Repo")
```

I am having trouble wrapping my head around how to properly make this relationship.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [remote_side](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_1/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship.params.remote_side) directive

```
class Repo(Base):
    __tablename__ = "repos"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Text, unique=True)
    parent_id = db.Column(Integer,db.ForeignKey('repos.id'))
    forks = relationship("Repo",
                backref=backref('parent', remote_side=[id])
            )
```

See [Adjacency List Relationships](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_1/orm/self_referential.html#adjacency-list-relationships) documentation and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16739234)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this would work?

```
class Repo(Base):
    __tablename__ = "repos"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Text, unique=True)


class Fork(Repo):
    __tablename__ = "forks"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = db.Column(Integer,db.ForeignKey('repos.id'))
    parent = db.relationship("Repo")
```

Inherit the Repo Class, so that the Fork shares all the same attributes as a Repo. Additionally, we add a relationship in the Fork which desginates it is not a root repository, and is associated to some previously forked repo

Comment: I haven't tried subclassing Models with SQLAlchemy, so this is a good idea. I tried your example, but go this error: `SAWarning: Could not assemble any primary keys for locally mapped table 'forks' - no rows will be persisted in this Table.
  self._configure_pks()`

Comment: Its more than likely my example is not proper, as I did it on the fly to illustrate the concept, but check out http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative/inheritance.html for subclassing   ... I edited with an explicit ID column set to PK for fork

Comment: you can also research `polymorphic_identity` as in this SO question .... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337095/sqlalchemy-inheritance